# Issue with the changing of the orientation of the screen on an html5 home screen app on iOS 11

Tags: javascript, html, ios11

When changing orientation from portrait to landscape on a mobile web app (using meta "apple-mobile-web-app-capable" - launched from the home screen icon) a black bar appears at the top of the screen, pushing the content down.

Steps to Reproduce:
1. Once bookmarked, launch the web app from the home screen icon in portrait mode.
2. At any moment, switch orientation to landscape.
3. Black bar from top of the screen pushes down the viewport content.

After this, a black bar appears causing the app to not be full screen anymore.

I tried using viewport-fit cover or contain in the meta tag, but nothing happened.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**The IOS 11** **isn't** a real criteria for a specific **resolution**  ***depend of the device used***. you have to add some media queries for every devices wanted : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_common_resolutions

Now you have to target what you want : just add some new sizes with (portrait-landscape) using CSS.

Open a media query @media add property with targetting and the orientation and we can use inside new specific property CSS for this situation.

```
@media only screen and (width : 603px) and (orientation: portrait) {
    #device:after {
        content: "Nexus 7 - portrait - chrome";
    }
}
@media only screen and (device-width : 1280px) and (orientation: landscape) {
    #device:after {
       content: "Nexus 7 - landscape - firefox";
    }
}
```